# Blazor with Fluxor: Can i have multiple instances of the same store?

Tags: redux, blazor, blazor-webassembly, fluxor

Is there any way to have multiple instances of a store?
I am actually trying to fill a grid layout with thumbnails (which contain buttons and other stuff).
I want to outsource the items in a separate component, using its own instance of the same store.

I don't know if that's even a good solution. It's the only one i came up with so far.
Anyone has a better idea how to solve this?

What is important to me, is that each thumbnail is loaded when its component is rendered. While it is loading it should display a loading spinner.

[image: Screenshot of my .Net Core MVC implementation]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good approach. The purpose of the state is to exist once and be available to all.

What you need is state that holds a collection of `FileState` (or whatever you want to call it) which has all the info it needs, including `bool IsLoading`.